# dask drop duplicates performance

Tags: dataframe, dask, scalability

I'm trying to get the function df.drop_duplicates() work as expected but I have performance and scalability issues.

My infrastructure contains a client (for now let's make it a jupyter) and a dask cluster with 15 workers 1cpu and 9GB memory each.

The data is a bunch of parquet files ( lets assume 2 Gb) containing 2kk rows of text data and I need to deduplicate all posts by an origin URL
After calling:

```
    some_file='s3://my_bucket/uploader/8953053034-tf4csv/parquet'
    df = dd.read_parquet(some, storage_options={'key': s3.key, 'secret': s3.secret})
    dedup_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Url'], split_out=df.npartitions)
```

the cluster at the beginning works ok and quite quickly but when getting to the finish it starts to slow down until nothing happens.
At first I needed to increase timeouts for connectivity scheduler<->workers to 60s as due to load on workers:

```
dask-worker 
dask-worker Traceback (most recent call last):
dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2122, in handle_missing_dep
dask-worker     who_has = await retry_operation(self.scheduler.who_has, keys=list(deps))
dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 390, in retry_operation
dask-worker     operation=operation,
dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 370, in retry
dask-worker     return await coro()
dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 858, in send_recv_from_rpc
dask-worker     comm = await self.pool.connect(self.addr)
dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 1013, in connect
dask-worker     **self.connection_args,
dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 245, in connect
dask-worker     _raise(error)
dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 215, in _raise
dask-worker     raise IOError(msg)
dask-worker OSError: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://dask-scheduler:8786' after 10 s: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://dask-scheduler:8786' after 10 s: connect() didn't finish in time
dask-worker 2020-07-30 10:59:24,987 - distributed.worker - ERROR - Handle missing dep failed, retrying
dask-worker Traceback (most recent call last):
dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 234, in connect
dask-worker     _raise(error)
dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 215, in _raise
dask-worker     raise IOError(msg)
dask-worker OSError: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://dask-scheduler:8786' after 10 s: connect() didn't finish in time
```

but even when I've increased the timeout the processing freezes and nothing happening on the cluster after the initial processing phase...
The dask UI shows (stands still for last 20 mins, no extra logs on workers and scheduler):
[image]

I've played with a number of partitions but there was no significant difference.

What can I do to successfully dedup 60-80GB of data in dask?

Update:
I tried a larger file (15Gb) and got nanny action that caused process to be killed

```
dask-worker-5d64694d56-bh6mv dask-worker 2020-07-30 12:49:12,403 - distributed.core - INFO - Event loop was unresponsive in Worker for 15.88s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
dask-worker-5d64694d56-xdmvf dask-worker 2020-07-30 12:49:12,426 - distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker process 14 was killed by signal 9
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker 2020-07-30 12:49:12,455 - distributed.worker - ERROR - Worker stream died during communication: tcp://192.168.117.111:42609
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker Traceback (most recent call last):
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 184, in read
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker     n_frames = await stream.read_bytes(8)
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker 
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker 
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker Traceback (most recent call last):
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 1983, in gather_dep
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker     self.rpc, deps, worker, who=self.address
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 3258, in get_data_from_worker
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker     return await retry_operation(_get_data, operation="get_data_from_worker")
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 390, in retry_operation
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker     operation=operation,
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 370, in retry
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker     return await coro()
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 3245, in _get_data
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker     max_connections=max_connections,
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 644, in send_recv
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker     response = await comm.read(deserializers=deserializers)
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 199, in read
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker     convert_stream_closed_error(self, e)
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 123, in convert_stream_closed_error
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker     raise CommClosedError("in %s: %s" % (obj, exc))
dask-worker-5d64694d56-58vxw dask-worker distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError: in <closed TCP>: Stream is closed
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker 2020-07-30 12:49:12,479 - distributed.worker - ERROR - Worker stream died during communication: tcp://192.168.117.111:42609
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker Traceback (most recent call last):
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 193, in read
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker     n = await stream.read_into(frame)
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker 
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker 
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker Traceback (most recent call last):
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 1983, in gather_dep
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker     self.rpc, deps, worker, who=self.address
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 3258, in get_data_from_worker
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker     return await retry_operation(_get_data, operation="get_data_from_worker")
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 390, in retry_operation
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48dask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4f  dask-workerdask-worker  2020-07-30 12:49:12,494 - distributed.worker - ERROR - Worker stream died during communication: tcp://192.168.117.111:42609
    operation=operation,
dask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4f dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48dask-worker  Traceback (most recent call last):
dask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4fdask-worker  dask-worker  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 370, in retry
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 184, in read
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4f dask-workerdask-worker      n_frames = await stream.read_bytes(8)
    return await coro()
dask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4f dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48dask-worker  tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed
dask-workerdask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4f    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 3245, in _get_data
dask-worker 
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48dask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4f  dask-workerdask-worker  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    max_connections=max_connections,
dask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4f dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48dask-worker  
dask-workerdask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4f    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 644, in send_recv
dask-worker Traceback (most recent call last):
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4f dask-workerdask-worker      response = await comm.read(deserializers=deserializers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 1983, in gather_dep
dask-worker-5d64694d56-4ml4fdask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48  dask-worker dask-worker    self.rpc, deps, worker, who=self.address
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 199, in read
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker     convert_stream_closed_error(self, e)
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 123, in convert_stream_closed_error
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker     raise CommClosedError("in %s: %s" % (obj, exc))
dask-worker-5d64694d56-htf48 dask-worker distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError: in <closed TCP>: Stream is closed
```

Comment: Hi Luke, can you have duplicates in different file? I mean is it possible that `file2` contains the duplicate for `file1` or are they independent? In the first case i don't think that dask could be of much help. In the second case you can use `delayed` and drop duplicates file by file.